# Page views countng in php

Tags: php, mysql

Im looking for some help with a page views counter in php.

suppose when user viewing a profile page and spend minimun 10 seconds time on that page
then i have to calculate view as 1...
so how to do that??

I have stored all profile details in a database and all pulled through the same template page, like profile.php?id=12345.

can anybody give me sample example

I tried it something like this..

```
$query = mysql_query(" UPDATE views SET views + 1 WHERE id = '$id' ");
```

Comment: Add a Javascript script which waits 10 seconds and then posts to a PHP script that records the view.

Comment: your query is invalid anyways, `... set views=views+1 ... `

Answer (score 3):

You can track individual users to your site by using PHP Sessions

https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php

then for each load of the page you can put a temporary record in the database and after a set period of time, you mentioned 10 seconds, send an AJAX call to a script that confirms the record as a view.

Answer (score 1):

You can send an ajax request to your server after 10 seconds has passed.

Please check [Timing events](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp).

Then send an [ajax request](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to your server after your specified time.

Upon receiving the request at server, you can do your own stuffs like updating the counter or whatever you wish.

Checking your updated question, i believe you need correction in your query. It will be like:

```
$query = mysql_query(" UPDATE views SET views = views + 1 WHERE id = '$id' ");
```

However, you SHOULD [escape](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) your `$id`.

Comment: I have a poor knowledge in AJAX.. can anybody give me a solution along with php and mysql

Comment: It's simple. However, if you want to improve yourself, please try something and post it back. We will try to help you then. Just make a get/post to a page that will update the counting like: `$.get('http://domain.com/hitcounter.php?id=111')`. Replace '111' with your current page ID and domain, pages etc. accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can refer [this](http://www.hotscripts.com/blog/track-your-visitors-using-php/) script, which uses `$_SERVER` and gets your count dumped in the MySQL.

A simple PHP Page Count would be this way:

```
<?php
    $countfile = ("countfile.txt");
    $hits = file($countfile);
    $hits[0] ++;
    $fp = fopen($countfile , "w");
    fputs($fp , "$hits[0]");
    fclose($fp);
    echo $hits[0];
?>
```